# TypeScript Union Type missing properties

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have 3 Types:

```
export type FooInitialStateType = {
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
  Email: string;
  Password: string
};

export type BarInitialStateType = {
  Id: string;
  Balance: number;
};

export type BazInitialStateType = {
  Id: string;
  Limit: number;
};
```

Which I then create a Union Type like so:

```
export type FooBarBazType = FooInitialStateType | BarInitialStateType | BazInitialStateType
```

I then have a generic method which processes arrays containing all 3 above Types:

```
  getFooBarBaz (
    events: FooBarBazType[]
  ): {
    foobarbaz0: FooBarBazType;
  } {
    const foobarbaz0 = <FooBarBazType>events[0];
    return {
      foobarbaz0
    };
  }
```

I then call this generic method from each class (foo, bar, baz):

```
    const {
      foobarbaz0
    }: {
      foobarbaz0: FooInitialStateType;
    } = this.getFooBarBaz(fooEvents);
```

I get a TS error:

> Type 'FooBarBazType' is not assignable to type 'FooInitialStateType'.

Because `FooInitialStateType` doesn't contain properties from `BarInitialStateType` and `BazInitialStateType`.

Actual questions:

1. How can I utilise the Union Type for the generic method to accept an array with all 3 Types, but then where I invoke the method, specify what exact Type the returned value should be?
2. Is a Union Type the correct thing to use here? I have one method that accepts 3 different Types, and produces one Type. I need the invoking function to know, and specify, the returned Type

Comment: You can use a type assertion to override the compiler but...you can't (essentially) downcast safely here. Not according to the compiler. I'm not sure a union type is what you really need - isn't this more the job of a generic?

Comment: @VLAZ If you could elaborate, that'd be great!

Comment: Well, it seems that you expect an array of *one* type of element and that element would be either `Foo` or `Bar` or `Baz` and the result would be one of the same type. The typings you've described here mean you can accept any combination of `Foo`/`Bar`/`Baz` items and the result would be one of these but there is no guarantee which one. So, it's perfectly valid, according to the compiler, to feed the method an array of `Foo` items and produce `Baz`. Or any combination really.

Comment: You seem to be trying to find an instance of one subtype amidst an array of others of the same supertype, in which case (in terms of both the typing and the actual functionality) you should probably read  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: The code here doesn't seem to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask].  For example, `fooEvents` is not declared anywhere.  Ideally the code could be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it would demonstrate the issue you're facing and only that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you want `getFooBarBaz()` to be a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function where the output type depends on the input type:

```
function getFooBarBaz<T extends FooBarBazType>(events: T[]): { foobarbaz0: T; } {
    const foobarbaz0 = events[0];
    return {
        foobarbaz0
    };
}
```

Then it might behave the way you'd like:

```
const fooEvents = [
    {
        Id: "foo",
        Name: "Foobert",
        Email: "foobert@example.com",
        Password: "Emb4rr4ss|ngP455w%?d"
    }
];

const {
    foobarbaz0
}: {
    foobarbaz0: FooInitialStateType;
} = getFooBarBaz(fooEvents); // no error now
```

Does that help?  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBiEIEkB2BLGPAQwBsBlGImYAFWVQF44BvAKDg7iwBMAuOAM4woeHAHMA3O04A5IgFtg-ISPFTOcAKLyieEsuGjJ0jgAUiAgQHdofQYfGsAvlNahIsBPTgAhIlFwCYnJKajoUOCY2DR4DVWMNPxIiHABjJTgcAFd5ACNgKCkXVjdwaHgkCL8AL0DCUgoqWm8oky47FSN1TgAZPHkCfmy8gqL1Uo8K7wwIPyga8MZ0TDrgxrDvAB9ff1WG0OaI7Zq9kKbFkoAzLLTCCBw4MWAYGbmagB4aOFBqHG4BZazfwLegAPgAFMAAG7AHAwAT8GgAbQAugBKfjMOCXTC5fx46oABkREjgThYbVS9yE2Nx+KIRMi3xhcIESMJKO6HCgzyyUAe0Q0nBxEDxUAJhLaxScJSpOBpIs0LPhTKRbUFQva-AARCLtQAaNoaOSKHUzfKwA1GzjaXT6OC63EFGAAAVACjAJGAADoqfIrZqzBZrLYddpcgAWKBQCOWTbiUwRgCsSasAFIAPzcbVS1ic2XU+Aa2mi+lE5yYtoisUS-gzU7rQ7AIpMp4vTBvBngxXKgRoiRAA)